# Unexpected results on difference of unsigned ints

Tags: c

I was surprised that this function produces different values for dif1 and dif2

```
void test()
{
    unsigned int x = 0, y = 1;
    long long dif1 = x - y;
    long long dif2 = (int)(x - y);
    printf("dif = %lld %lld",dif1,dif2);
}
```

Is that correct behavior?  In the dif1 computation it first promotes the 32-bit unsigned difference to a 64-bit unsigned value, then adds the sign.  Is that standard behavior, not specified by the language, or a compiler bug?  Is the second form guaranteed to produce -1, or up to the compiler implementation?  I guess the safest construction is:
long long dif3 = (long long)x - (long long)y;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first one is definitely defined, if we assume that `long long` is wider than `unsigned int`. If it isn't, then the assignment gives the same problem as the second part of the answer.

```
long long dif1 = x - y;
```

Unsigned integers will wrap and you get a maximum value that can be stored in an unsigned int.

> 6.2.5  p9: A computation involving unsigned operands can never overflow,
>   because a result that cannot be represented by the resulting unsigned integer type is
>   reduced modulo the number that is one greater than the largest value that can be
>   represented by the resulting type.

As for the second

```
long long dif2 = (int)(x - y);
```

it is implementation defined:

> 6.3.1.3 p3: Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the
>   result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.

In this case a maximum value for `unsigned int` cannot be represented in an `int` ant the above rule is in effect.

Comment: I guess it is also the case that int dif = x - y is implementation defined when y is greater than x.  So, you really should never take the difference of unsigned integers unless you want the unsigned modulo result.

Comment: I guess this also means that abs(x-y) does not necessarily equal abs(y-x) when x and y are unsigned ints.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing surprising about it.

```
unsigned int x = 0, y = 1;
long long dif1 = x - y;
long long dif2 = (int)(x - y);
```

The second has one difference to the first:

A cast to `signed`.
The cast is defined to be value-preserving if possible (Not possible as `UINT_MAX` is bigger than `INT_MAX`), and otherwise **implementation-defined** (though it is allowed to trap).

If we have 2s-complement on cast (likely), the result of the cast is `-1`.

Next, we have an assignment to a wider signed type, which is always value-preserving.

Comment: I had figured there was an implicit cast to "signed" in the assignment to a signed value dif1.  But, apparently the size extension happens first. i.e., dif1 = (signed) ((unsigned long long) (x - y))